# Strange HDD sound

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Windows 7 x64 on SSD, second disk is Samsung Spinpoint F3 HDD for storage. While there is no known usage of HDD by me I could hear the sound of "dhak-dhak-dhak-dhak...", about 10 "dhak's" during 1 second in every 30 minutes.

What is causing this?

Comment: Stuck head? Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Isn't that data under stuck head is inaccessible? Anyway HD Tune "Health" tab reports "Ok" for everything. Where do I should look for SMART errors or status in HD Tune?

Comment: Not necessarily, the noise may be from trouble parking the heads. Check if your disk is set to power down after 30 minutes.

Comment: No, power-downs are disabled. Tried a few "disk programs", none of them found errors. And this "dhak-dhak..." is coming under Linux too, so I think it must be some "feature" of the disk itself.